# How to track number of times user has been authenticated via azure ad

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, adal

I am using Azure Ad and ADAL.js for authentication of my application, I need to track the number of times the user has successfully visited the application.

- if the user is visiting the application in the same session then it should be counted as 1 visit.
- if the user browse the application in different session then it should be counted as second visit.

Is there any event in ADAL.js that i can use?

or i am thinking to store session-state(adal.session.state) value in the database, which i have monitored is changing if the user session is changed.i will then compare this value for every visit of user it value is changed then i will increase the number of visit and will also update the new session state value.

Answer (score 0):

i created two extra column in my database Visits, SessionStateValue Value

Since i was getting session state value which adal.js was storing in the session storage so whenever user logs in to the system successfully, and there is no value present in SessionStateValue db column(which means user is logging for the first time) then i store the session state value in db and increase the visit count by 1.

When the user uses the application within same session(say a new browser tab is opened ), since the SessionStateValue value is present in db and matches with the Session state value of browser then no visit count is increased.

If the user login in other session(browser closed and reopened or different browser is used) then session state value is changed and is appended to the SessionStateValue in db and visit count is increased by 1.

this logic is used as long as the visit count is < 3.